# Ajax and sophisticated graphics in Java web-app

Tags: java, web-applications, jsf, spring-mvc

In my opinion WWW will sooner or later come to full-blown AJAX web-sites, so that we wouldn't have
page reloads every time you click somewhere.

Now I want you to ask this.

**What tools and frameworks can one use to make a Java Web-application running on Tomcat**

have AJAX functionality  like "in-place, with no page reloading" table sorting by

clicking on its column header, multi-tabs that enable opening at once the new screen to the user without reloading a page,  saving data in the database without reloading a page, and other similar things that we do not usually see on web pages.

That's all should probably be based on AJAX.

But how to integrate this AJAX functionality with existing java web-frameworks, let's say Spring MVC?

Or maybe there are other frameworks that better suit such needs but that can be integrated with core Spring?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Java applications are totally different from webpages. They can execute things in the background. The J in ajax stands for Javascript.

Comment: Also note that anachronism is not friendly for search engines and for people that uses non-is browsers. So I don't think it will be fully Ajax based.

Comment: yes, but it would have been cool if the framework generated this JS code automatically based on components you used.

Comment: what I've come across by the way: RichFaces is a component library for JSF and an advanced framework for easily integrating AJAX capabilities into business applications.

Comment: Why don't you learn javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is rather confusing--AJAX calls are all client-side, any server-side technology can return data to the client.

That being said, you may try taking a look at [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/overview.html).

> With the GWT SDK, you write your AJAX front-end in the Java programming language which GWT then cross-compiles into optimized JavaScript that automatically works across all major browsers. During development, you can iterate quickly in the same "edit - refresh - view" cycle you're accustomed to with JavaScript, with the added benefit of being able to debug and step through your Java code line by line. When you're ready to deploy, the GWT compiler compiles your Java source code into optimized, standalone JavaScript files.

Among other things, GWT supports built-in serialization of objects for transfer to your Java servlets, allowing for crazy-easy (the technical term) integration of your GWT client and existing Java technologies.

Answer (score 1):

Homebrewed/3rd-party Ajax stuff with JSF isn't that easy since you have to take its lifecycle and component tree into account. You would need to write your own `ViewHandler`. Rather look for what's already available. To start, JSF2 already provides builtin Ajax functionality with under each `<f:ajax>`. There are further also a lot of Ajaxical JSF component libraries, like [RichFaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces) ([showcase here](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTable.jsf)).

No wording about Spring as I don't do it.